# Uso del metodo aggregate() de mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, moongose

tengo una coleccion de usuarios donde quiero buscar de forma individual a cada usuario por su dni, de esta forma realice la consulta:

`const r = User.aggregate([{ $match: { dni: "27380840" }}]);`

y de respuesta me devuelve por consola lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo que puedo hacerlo con el método find(), aunque para esta ocasión no sería optimo

Comment: Evita el uso de imagenes al momento de publicar código o resultados de consola o error. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para cambiar lo que haga falta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Al contrario, `find` es menos costoso que `aggregate`. Siempre que puedas evitar una agregación, evítala. Sólo úsala cuando `find` no sea capaz de lograr el resultado esperado.

Por otro lado, el método [`aggregate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-aggregate) de un Modelo de Mongoose devuelve un Objeto de tipo [Aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Aggregate).

Por lo tanto, para que tu consulta funcione debes o bien usarla dentro de un entorno `async` con `await`, y encadenando el método [`exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exechttps://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec), para que te devuelva efectivamente una Promesa:

```js
// dentro de una función o entorno async
try {
  const r = await User.aggregate([{ $match: { dni: "27380840" }}]).exec();
  console.log(r);
}
catch(e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

O puedes usar una función `callback`:

```js
User.aggregate([{ $match: { dni: "27380840" }}], (error, result) => {
  if(error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    return;
  }
  console.log(result);
});
```

También podrías usar el método [`then`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-then) ya que el Objeto Aggregate es *thenable*:

```js
User.aggregate([{ $match: { dni: "27380840" }}])
  .then(
    r => {
      // manejo el resultado
    },
    e => {
      // manejo el error
    }
  );
```

O tal vez más parecido a `then` y `catch` de una Promesa:

```js
User.aggregate([{ $match: { dni: "27380840" }}])
  .then(r => {
    // manejo el resultado
  })
  .catch(e => {
      // manejo el error
  });
```

Cuando haces lo siguiente:

```js
const r = User.aggregate([{ $match: { dni: "27380840" }}]);
```

estás asignando a la variable `r` un Objeto de tipo Aggregate y no el resultado de la agregación.

**NOTA:**

Si bien el Objeto Aggregate implementa `then` y `catch`, el mismo no es una Promesa.